# Creating ansible playbook for cronjob with random minute and hour

Tags: random, ansible, cron

I have the following Ansible playbook to create a cronjob on red hat Linux servers, this works well, but the problem is that it runs every time irrespective of whether the same cronjob is already present or not. I know it runs because it generates new hour and minute values every time. Is there any way to make it not run when this job is already present in crontab?

```
- hosts: all 
  tasks:
   - name: Generate randon minute
     set_fact:
       random_minute: "{{ 59 | random }}"
     run_once: yes
   - debug: var=random_minute

   - name: Generate random hour
     set_fact:
       random_hour: "{{ 23 | random }}"
     run_once: yes
   - debug: var=random_hour
   
   - name: "Cronjob Entry"
     cron:
      name: "### oscompliance cronjob"
      minute: "{{ random_minute }}" 
      hour: "{{ random_hour }}" 
      day: "*"
      month: "*"
      weekday: "*"
      job: /users/user1/scripts/os_check >> /tmp/os_checkoutput 2>&1
```